# Argument "*" isn't numeric in array element

Tags: perl

I want to make a hash of array from a file that looks like:

```
xx500173:56QWER  45   A    rtt34  34C
...
```

I would like to have a unique "key" (e.g. column1_column2)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


my $seq;
while(<>){
chomp;
my @line = split(/\s+/, $_);

my $key = $line[0] . "_" . $line[1]; #try to make a unique key for each entry

map { $seq->{ $_->[$key] } = [@$_[0..4]] } [ split/\s+/ ];
}

foreach my $s (keys %{$seq} ) {
print $s,": ",join( "\t", @{ $seq->{$s}} ) . "\n";
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
Argument "xx500173:56QWER_45" isn't numeric in array element
```

Does is it matter if key is numeric or string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index to an array `[]` should be numeric, but `$key` is not numeric.  Assuming you want all the white-space-separated tokens as elements of your array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $seq;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split;
    my $key = $line[0] . "_" . $line[1]; #try to make a unique key for each entry
    $seq->{$key} = [ @line ];
}

foreach my $s ( keys %{$seq} ) {
    print $s, ": ", join( "\t", @{ $seq->{$s} } ) . "\n";
}

__DATA__
xx500173:56QWER  45   A    rtt34  34C
```

Outputs:

```
xx500173:56QWER_45: xx500173:56QWER     45      A       rtt34   34C
```

Answer (score 1):

You have confused yourself with the line

```
map { $seq->{ $_->[$key] } = [@$_[0..4]] } [ split/\s+/ ];
```

which is wrong because

- `map` is an operator for translating one list into another by performing the same operation on every element of the input list, but you are ignoring the returned value
- The input list is only one item long - the array reference returned by `[ split/\s+/ ]`

What you have written is the same as

```
$_ = [ split /\s+/ ];
$seq->{ $_->[$key] } = [ @$_[0..4] ];
```

and the problem is that `$_->[$key]` tries to index the anonymous array using the string `$key`, which is clearly wrong.

All you need here is

```
$seq->{$key} = [ @line[0..4] ];
```

and your complete program should look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq;

while ( <> ) {
  chomp;
  my @line = split;

  $seq->{"$line[0]_$line[1]"} = [ @line[0..4] ];
}

for my $s ( keys %{$seq} ) {
  printf "%s: %s\n", $s, join("\t", @{ $seq->{$s} } );
}
```